# Play Framework use Joined Table in Query (ExpressionList)

Tags: java, playframework, entities, ebean, playframework-2.2

So I have two tables: Users and AlertHistory.

I have joined AlertHistory to User, so that if I do:

```
 List<User> users = new Model.Finder(Integer.class, User.class).setMaxRows(9).findList();
 List<AlertHistory> ahc = users.get(3).getAlertHistoryCollection();
```

I will get the list of Users, and each user will have a collection of AlertHistory objects.

What I would like to do with the Finder, is return the list of Users where the AlertHistory is NOT NULL. I've tried various version of:

```
new Model.Finder(Integer.class, User.class).where().isNotNull("alertHistoryCollection").setMaxRows(9).findList();
```

but to no avail.

Comment: `isNotNull()` works just fine on my DB, so cannot reproduce this. Care to add some more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that the relationships I had defined weren't correct.

In `User.java`:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
private List<AlertHistory> alertHistoryList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and in `AlertHistory.java`:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
```

Once I got the relationship annotated and typed correctly, it started working as expected, so that if the `User` has associated `AlertHistory`'s, they will populate, and if not, the collection will be empty. `.isNotNull()` now works as expected.